# $this->Auth->user() does not return 'id'

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am testing a migration from 1.3 to 2.0 for an Intranet site. After logging on an existing user, `print_r($this->Auth->user());` returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [username] => keith
    [password] => f793ff5af0ea72013679a4635f40fbfaa5808895
)
```

Theuser is defined in the Users table, so I would have expected to see all of the fields which are defined in the Users table, which is the behaviour under 1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.0 `$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)` will log the user in with whatever data is posted, whereas in 1.3 `$this->Auth->login($this->data)` would try to identify the user first and only log in when successful.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in

I'm guessing you passed data to your `$this->Auth->login()` method. `$this->Auth->login()` will authenticate and login with the form data POSTed without passing the data in (which will log in the user no matter what).